# SQS not sending message to Eventbridge (Serverless framework)

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-event-bridge

I'm send messages to SQS which is supposed to send them to eventbridge that is going to trigger lambda.

I can see messages received in SQS, but somehow it is not sending them to Eventbridge.

This is my serverless config

```yaml
service: mysendemail

projectDir: ../
frameworkVersion: "3"

package:
  individually: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: eu-west-1
  timeout: 30
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

  environment:
    STAGE: "dev"
    QUEUE_URL: https://sqs.${aws:region}.amazonaws.com/${aws:accountId}/my-sqs-message-dev
  iamRoleStatements:
      Action:
        - sqs:SendMessage
      Resource: 
        !GetAtt MySQSMessageQueue.Arn

functions:
  pushMessage:
    handler: ./src/index.pushMessage
    events:
      - http:
          path: message/push
          method: post
          cors: true
  sendEmail:
    handler: ./src/index.sendEmail
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          pattern:
            source:
              - 'aws.sqs'
            resources:
              - !GetAtt MySQSMessageQueue.Arn

resources:
  Resources:
    #SQS Queue
    MySQSMessageQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: my-sqs-message-dev
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Please read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html EventBridge is not involved in the AWS Lambda SQS integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQS is not a source for EventBridge. Also, EventBridge it is not working on message content but more on management events.

You can find a list of sources for EventBridge: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html